# Is window example of Singleton objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, dom, singleton, tdd

While reading this [article](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/) I thought to relate this to some practical example so, I got curious about the `window` object. Since we can't instantiate it and it only has a single instance during the lifetime of any program hence it should satisfy the criteria.

Above is my opinion but I want to know the truth and also, all the points said in the given article are applicable to the `window` object in general?

**Update1**

As quoted in the give article:

> Singletons are nothing more than global state

So, in general the global state makes testing harder by hiding dependencies, how do we deal with such restrictions in javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really a singleton, because you can create a new instance with the [`Window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) function. The return value is a reference to the same object scripts within that scripts within that new window will see as their global `window` object.

I would clarify that singletons are *a kind* of global state, but it's not the only kind. And true, anything defined on the current `window` object is visible anywhere within your script. So the `window` directly represents your global state, even though it's not technically a `Singleton`.

Now, with regards to your second question, how can you deal with the fact that JavaScript has a global scope during testing? Well that's a lot harder. Even in environments that don't have a `window` object, like [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html), there it still some set of global objects. Things like enabling [strict mode](http://strict%20mode/) can go a long way to avoid accidentally creating variables in the global scope, and you may be able to prevent a function from adding to the global state like this (I'm not sure if this is advisable, but it works):

```
"use strict"
Object.preventExtensions(window);

function testfunc() {
  window.someVar = 0; // Can't add property x, object is not extensible
  console.log("testfunc", window.someVar);
}
```

But I don't think you'd be able to completely eliminate the possibility of global state affecting your code. A common example is the `window.name` property that can show up in unexpected places, like this:

```
"use strict"
Object.preventExtensions(window);

function testfunc() {
  console.log("testfunc", name); // perfectly valid
}
```

Some static analysis tools like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) can help to catch these types of errors.

Comment: Well I would see it as an exceptional case then, I am talking in general i.e. while we care executing our javascript code.

Comment: @CodeYogi Yeah, It *looks* like a singleton in many ways, but in truth it's not. You might call it a 'psuedo-singleton'.

Comment: what suggestions you have regarding testing with global states like `window`? can we mock it?

Comment: @CodeYogi I suppose you could mock it up if you wrapped your code in `function(window) { ... }(mockWindow)`. Then any accesses to `window.X` would access `mockWindow` instead, but you still have the problem that any code inside that accessed `name` (not `window.name`) would still be accessing the browser's `window`.